# Reference request for Prüfer groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, abelian-groups

It will be very helpful for me if I get a reference(notes/book e.t.c) where I can get details about Prüfer groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the very good references would be

**An Introduction to the Theory of Groups** by *J. J. Rotman*. In Chapter $10$ which is about abelian groups, you  will see some valuable remarks and strong facts about free abelian groups and after that as a very good and practical theorem you'll see that.

> **Theorem $10.13$:** There is an **infinite** $p-$primary group $G=\mathbb Z(p^{\infty})$ each of whose proper subgroups is **finite** (and cyclic).

Moreover, you'll find very interesting facts (at least for me) stating that:

- $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z\cong\sum_p\mathbb Z(p^{\infty})$.
- $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z\cong\prod_p\mathbb Z(p^{\infty})\cong\bf{T}\cong \mathbb R\oplus(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$.
- And if $G$ is an infinite group such that every proper subgroup is finite then for a proper prime $p$, $G\cong\mathbb Z(p^{\infty})$.

Comment: Nice reference. You like your Rotman! ;-) +1

Comment: @amWhy: Somehow, it becomes my Bible.

Comment: @BabakS.: I agree, this is a very nice reference +1